# geom_tex rotate text for specific data only

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I produce the following plot using this command:

```
ggplot(ToPlot, aes(x=Pop, y=Val, fill=Categorie)) +   
         geom_bar(stat="identity") +
         facet_grid( ~ Soft,scales="free_x") +   
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +    
         geom_text(aes(label= Val), size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3, position =     "stack")
```

However, as you can see for the dataset called "S", I would like to rotate them but only for this dataset. Do you know how I can do that ?

Thanks!

Eddie
[image]

Comment: You can probably do `geom_text(aes(..., angle = ifelse(needs_rotating_test, rotation_angle, 0)))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works , wasn't aware could include a test directly in geom_text.
The text is a bit off; it is not on the column as it is with no angle change tho'.

Comment: You can use the same idea and apply it to the `hjust` or `vjust` value inside `aes()` too.  Ex: `aes(..., hjust = ifeise(...), vjust=ifelse(... `